# Language neutral plugin architectures

Tags: c#, java, delphi, plugins, com-interop

I am looking at extending an existing application through the use of a plugin architecture. The application id written in Delphi, but I want to be able to implement various plugins in whatever language is best of the job. Currently we have skills in Delphi, C# and Java, and would like to be able to implement a plugin in whatever language is required.

Does anyone know of an example system that can be used to implement this ?

I am assuming that I could standardise on a particular COM interface and anything that implements that interface could be a plugin.

Does anyone have any pointers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good overview of a COM-based plugin system that works in both Delphi and C++Builder:

[Implementing a Plug-in Framework](http://www.techvanguards.com/com/tutorials/plugin.asp)

Comment: This is probably closest to what I need, I now need to know how to make a plugin that matches the interface in C#.

Comment: To get the C# implementation, just take the type library Delphi produces and import it into Visual Studio which will create everything you need, including a skeleton implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

For your C# plugin requirements, here is an example (from Rick Strahl) of hosting the .Net runtime in an unmanaged application (in this case FoxPro) and poking it via a COM interface:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/104449.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While I personaly haven't used it,
[RemObjects Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx) is a plugin framework designed to ease integration of Delphi and .NET.